# Implementing Singleton using factory method

Tags: java, singleton

I am trying to create a class that has a singleton property using a static factory method..

```
package ishan.Beans;

public class ControlManager {

    private static ControlManager controlManager=null;

    private  double id;

    private ControlManager()
    {
        this.id=Math.random();
    }

    public static ControlManager getControlManager()
    {

        if(null==controlManager)
            return new ControlManager();

        return controlManager;
    }

    public double getId() {
        return id;
    }

}


package ishan.Beans;

public class Usage {

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        ControlManager cManager=ControlManager.getControlManager();

        ControlManager c=ControlManager.getControlManager();

        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(cManager);
    }

}
```

Every time I run this code, I get different instances of ControlManager in c and cManager. I am unable to figure out the problem or what is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: And at which line exactly do you assign to `controlManager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving away the new instance you create... your code is:

> ```
> public static ControlManager getControlManager()
> {
>
>     if(null==controlManager)
>         return new ControlManager();
> ```

but should be:

```
public static ControlManager getControlManager() {

    if(controlManager == null) {
        controlManager = new ControlManager();
        return controlManager;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `getControlManager()`:

From

```
return new ControlManager();
```

to

```
controlManager = new ControlManager();
```

This is, what it should look like in the end:

```
public static ControlManager getControlManager() {
    if(controlManager == null) {
        controlManager = new ControlManager();
    }

    return controlManager;
}
```

In addition something opinion based, but backed up by conventions imo:
When writing conditional statements (`if`) the order of your conditions should stick to the way of naturally speaking the statement. Example:

- Bad: `if (null == contorlManager)`
- Good: `if (controlManager == null)`

The reason or goal behind this is, to keep your code readable. No one asks: "Is green the traffic light?".

For further information on this, see [Yoda Conditions](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the convention thing.i'll keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be change as:​

```
public static ControlManager getControlManager() {
    if(controlManager == null)controlManager = new ControlManager();          
    return controlManager;
}
```

Good Luck !!!